# How can I use my own fonts in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

I've been using LaTeX for bigger assignments at the university for two semesters now. At the moment I'm working on my final project and for that I want to use the company font.

I have it in OTF and TTF format. But I need help to get it into LaTeX.

I found some guides on the internet using the `T1` encoding - but it's not working. Hope some of you guys can help me.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Are you able to use Xe- or LuaLaTeX? Have you read the multiple posts on how to use `.otf` fonts in LaTeX?

Comment: The easiert would be to use one of the new engine xelatex or lualatex together with the package fontspec (see its documentation).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, your comment is clearly the or at least the canonical answer. Why don't you add it as one?

Comment: @Ruben: Because it is a comment and not a full answer. I don't have the time to add an example or something similar. Also there is certainly a duplicate somewhere ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, astonishingly the question has not been asked in this form yet; there are many XeTeX and LuaTeX related question concerning this topic though. I'll add an answer then...

Comment: @Ruben: Well "use otf" finds tons of relevant examples.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, well well, I would consider this basic knowledge or knowledge that could be very easily googled and of course, this is mentioned on very different spots on this site. But, as the question has not been specifically been asked yet... (And consider all the other generic questions on tex.sx, i.e. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The modern TeX engines (XeTeX and LuaTeX) together with the `fontspec` package are able to handle opentype and truetype fonts that are installed on the system. (Hence, you don't have "to get it into LaTeX" by yourself, as the engines will take care about it.) A minimal example looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{Arial} %resp. your company's font
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant
\end{document}
```

It is compilable both via `lualatex <filename>.tex` or `xelatex <filename>.tex`.