# A font style in LaTeX text

Tags: fonts

I feel the font in the following picture is very good-looking (though I don't quite like its *italics* part), better than the usual Times New Roman in my opinion:

[image]

So I want to use the same font in my LaTeX *main text*. Who can tell its name and how to use it in LaTeX amsbook and amsart? (E.g. what package I need to use?)

Comment: I don't think so. Knowing its name is one small issue, more importantly I want to use it in LaTeX, and I don't know how.

Comment: `\usepackage{ebgaramond,ebgaramond-maths}`

Comment: Your question has two questions in one, so also two types of related questions :) for the question "how to use a custom font in amsbook/amsart" there is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254245/how-can-i-use-my-own-fonts-in-latex or if a font package exists for this specific font then https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59403/what-font-packages-are-installed-in-tex-live can be helpful.

Comment: Thanks! I found it's *ETbb*: 
https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/etbb/

Comment: @egreg This is very useful, thank you very much!

Comment: @egreg As I said, I don't quite like its italics part, I only want to use it in the main text. Do you know if there is an easy way to keep things in theorem environments as before? (If not, that's fine, I can accept.) I find if I omit "ebgaramond-maths", then it will be as before in formulae. I also want to avoid it in italics/\emph in the main text.

Comment: The "y" of the etbb it is different than to that correct of ebgaramond, ebgaramond-maths as suggest brilliantly by @egreg.